# Multisite gives Error if i want to enter Dashboard or Site

Tags: multisite, dashboard, apache

I´m struggling for 3 days now. I want to create a Wordpress Multisite System with subdirectories. As Server im using Apache.
My wordpress is installed at /var/www/html/wordpress
In order to do so i followed the installation instruction and added to my wp-config.php

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'myadress');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

After this i change my .htaccess file to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Now i want to add a new page for this i click on the menu to add a new site. After adding if i want to go to the dashboard. But i always get an Error that says that the requested URL was not found on the Server.
I also enabled apache mod_rewrite.
As solution to show 2 websites i now created a subdirectory and installed a new version of wordpress there. Now i can see the second the dashboard and the site. But this is a new Instance or ? Because if i am in the Dashboard of the subdirectory i cant go back to the parent multisite dashboarf.
Has anybody an idea why that is the case ? I'm new to Wordpress and can't find the Solution.

Thanks for your Help

Moe

Comment: It's possible that a plugin is causing the error. Take a look at the error.log file in the site root and the admin folder and see what it tells you. You can temporarily disable all plugins by renaming the plugins folder. Or temporarily disable a particular plugin by renaming it's folder.